# PHP get a specific String with random values

Tags: php

I have a undivided big String array which looks kind of like this:

```
VALUES(1,1,1,0,1,"TEst",0,"NAME","URL.de","RANDOM CRYPRIC STUFF 34","­RANDOM CRYPRIC STUFF34 ","test",1,2)
VALUES(1,1,1,0,1,"TEst",0,"NAME","URL.de","RANDOM CRYPRIC STUFF 34","­RANDOM CRYPRIC STUFF34 ","test",1,2)
VALUES(1,1,1,0,1,"TEst",0,"NAME","URL.de","RANDOM CRYPRIC STUFF 34","­RANDOM CRYPRIC STUFF34 ","test",1,2)
```

The Values are all diffrent and my PHP code looks like this to get the individual Values:

```
$backupdat = fopen("text.txt","r");
while(!feof($backupdat))
   {
   $found1.= strchr(fgets($backupdat,1024),"VALUES");
   }
fclose($backupdat);


$whatIWant = explode("VALUES(",$found1);

$User= explode(",",$whatIWant[1]);
enter code here
echo $User[10]."--";    
echo $User[11]."--";
```

Now I can browse all things with Values by changing the Array "WhatIWant[X]" and $User[x].

The thing is the "Random Cryptic Stuff can be everything all chars including , " and newRow.
So my explode method gets the wrong input.

I'm now looking for some other way to get my values, the only thing fix in length is the Crypric stuff which is 34 chars long.

Comment: Must the data be saved in the format? Or could you use a conventional serialization method

Comment: One option is to explode as you are until the URL.de part, then count 34 chars past that to get random "crypric" stuff, then explode the rest as you were

Comment: @user574632 what do you mean the Data ? my two arrays or the Data i whant to split into pieces ? The Data Values(....) is fix i cant change that and the two arrays i used to get a quick methode for each individual value

Comment: @GEnGEr i mean the contents `text.txt`. If you can change how this is saved, json or phps serialize() would make retrieving values much easier

Comment: @user574632 nope the Text.txt is fix and not an option to change i need to work with the given stuff XD

Comment: Read a line at a time using `fgets()`; trim() to remove the trailing return; use `substr($line, 7, -1)` to strip off the leading `VALUES(` and trailing `)`; then use [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker i dont think its possible to use str_getcsv() it has the same problems as explode. The delimiter and enclosure Parameters could be in the cryptic part and than i get the wrong value again.

Comment: If the delimiter is in the "cryptic part" then it shouldn't matter, because it's wrapped in quotes.... you'll only have a problem if ___unescaped___ quotes appear in the "cryptic part".... but what doesn the "cryptic part" actually look like? Can it contain quotes? If so, are they escaped in any way?

Comment: LÔ.öße#ŽAÑÃ‹†pð‰‡øx*Ë","¯›Ÿm¼2q¥£áµÍ†yØˆÆd$CP£Õ}fí°¼í" this is what the Cryptic part looks like. It can realy be anything, most of the Chars cant be echoED and if i manualy coppy that part it dose not work. I realy need the original thing.

Comment: You should really go yell at the person who thought it was a good idea to save the data like this. Are the columns always the same types? (first 5 numbers, string, etc...)

Comment: @user3535256 the numbers are always numbers yes but the Strings can change. E.g Test Name and URL.de could all be numbers so it would youst be 1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,"RANDOM CRYPRIC STUFF 34"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is no clever way to do this. You could build your own parsing function, something like this:

```
$mystring = 'VALUES(1,1,1,0,1,"TEst",0,"NAME","URL.de","abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefgh","abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefgh","test",1,2)';

$stripped = substr($mystring, 7, strlen($mystring)-8);

function parsecol($string, &$index) {
  $val = '';
  if ($string[$index] == '"') {
    $limit = '"';
    $index++;
  } else {
    $limit = ',';
  }
  while (isset($string[$index]) && $string[$index] != $limit) {
    $val .= $string[$index];
    $index++;
  }
  if ($limit == '"') {
    $index++;
  }
  $index++;
  return $val;
}


$user = array();
$index = 0;
// parse first 9 columns
for ($i=0; $i<9; $i++){
  $user[] = parsecol($stripped, $index);
  var_dump($user);
}
// get the cryptic strings
$user[] = substr($stripped, $index+1, 34);
var_dump($user);
$index += 37; // pass 34 chars from crypt, 2 " and ,
$user[] = substr($stripped, $index+1, 34);
$index += 37;
for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
  $user[] = parsecol($stripped, $index);
}

var_dump($user);
```

Comment: works like a charm, last problem is its not that easy to get $mystring because of two things. 1. VALUES( is somewhere in the Text.txt and 2. to get the whole line without getting cut of by the cryptic stuff.